Alphabet size mismatch with model output shape | alphabet.GetSize()+1) == (class_dim)
Using the CTC Beam Search Decoder of DeepSpeech I get the following error:
[ctc_beam_search_decoder.cpp:279] FATAL: "(alphabet.GetSize()+1) == (class_dim)" check failed. Number of output classes in acoustic model does not match number of labels in the alphabet file. Alphabet file must be the same one that was used to train the acoustic model.
I have controlled the alphabet and it has the size of 1023, even though I built it with 1024 characters. The output shape of the model is 1025. I believe the mismatch is 1 character. I thought of blank or unk token, but I aint sure if that is the cause of the error. Any idea why this happens or how to solve it?
